# Idiomatic Translation: Guilty Pleasure

Tags: translation, idioms

jDictionary Advanced English Dictionary defines guilty pleasure as:

> **guilty pleasure**
>
> (idiomatic) Something that brings pleasure but is considered taboo, unadvisable or lowbrow. "For the renowned sushi chef, eating fish sticks drowned in tartar sauce was a guilty pleasure."

Not looking for things like: 罪恶的快感.

Hoping there's something more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about 恶趣味? Literally "an evil interest".

For your example,

> For the renowned sushi chef, eating fish sticks drowned in tartar sauce was a guilty pleasure.
>
> 对于一位有名望的寿司师傅，吃着配上塔塔酱的鱼柳条是种恶趣味。

Some other interesting translations include:

- 罪快乐. It takes the pronunciation of 最快乐 (happiest) to imply that it's the happiest, yet a "crime".
- 罪乐感. It derives from 罪恶感 (guilt) to imply that it's a guilt which makes one "happy".

Comment: 恶趣味 is good candidate. The other two are made-up words which don't meet the 'idiomatic' criteria.

Comment: @NS.X. Yup, I agree. Thanks for noting that!

Comment: @NS.X 痛并快乐着？快乐而又痛苦着？this is the closest thing I can think of, you see it often in chinese, the actually translation doesn't exactly match, but I think it is used more commonly to express the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I found these on douban.com, maybe they are helpful.

- 偶尔纵欲
- 暗爽

Answer (score 0):

罪恶的快乐 or 带罪恶感的快乐

For example, 罪恶的快乐 is used in this article: http://www.360doc.com/content/15/0301/14/11843203_451727066.shtml

Compared to 罪恶的快感, I think 罪恶的快乐 is slightly less ambiguous. 带罪恶感的快乐 is not ambiguous but lengthy. In Chinese, shorter sentences are preferred. Some ambiguity can be resolved by context. A slight criticism is in Chinese, precision cannot be achieved without accepted gramatical tools (functional words).

罪恶的快感 = the pleasure of being guilty (similar to 完美犯罪的快感，快乐杀人)
For example: http://blog.udn.com/godzillahome/20539898

罪恶的快乐 = the pleasure mixed with some guilty feeling